# Run a AHK function or statement only once, after any member of set of keys is pressed and held down

Tags: autohotkey

So in this case I am asking AHK to press shift twice with the following functions.

```
ShiftPress(delay){
        send {Shift Down}
        Sleep, delay
        send {Shift Up}
        Sleep, delay
}

ShiftPressTwice(delay){
    ShiftPress(delay)
    ShiftPress(delay)
}
```

For this set of keys (Not sure if this is the best way to iterate over a set of keys, only using examples I have found online)

```
w::
a::
s::
d:: 
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
Space::
    ShiftPressTwice(10)
    while GetKeyState("Space")
    {
        Sleep, 10
    }
    Return
```

My thought is the above code is bit like  switch case fall through, then it should call my function `ShiftPressTwice(delay)` one time, then hit the `GetKeyState(key)` loop and sleep then bail. What happens is this seems to run in a endless loop. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
w::
a::
s::
d:: 
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
Space::
    ShiftPressTwice(10) 
    KeyWait %A_ThisHotkey%
    Return
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.